# Why does my contact form isn't working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fancybox

I'm trying to add to a website a contact form with Jquery and Fancybox.

All seems to doing well, the pop-up animation is ok, the mail seems to by sended but I'm not receiving any mail :(

Could someone help me to understand where is the problem ?

**Edit:**

-**I've checked my junk and spam folder**

-Here is the website link: [lacouleurdurendezvous.fr](http://www.lacouleurdurendezvous.fr)

-Someone talked about server misconfiguration, what is it ?

**EDIT:**

-It seems to be a server malfunction... I'm trying to conatct my web hoster...

**Here is how I call my scripts:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Ressources/retour.js"></script>
<script src="Ressources/testhead.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
```

**Here is the html code:**

```
<li id="menu"><a class="modalbox" href="#inline">Contactez Nous</a></li>

             <!-- hidden inline form -->
<div id="inline">
    <h2>Envoyez nous un email</h2>

    <form id="contact" name="contact" action="#" method="post">
        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="txt">
        <br>
        <label for="msg">Message</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="msg" class="txtarea"></textarea>

        <button id="send">Envoyer</button>
    </form>
</div>

<!-- basic fancybox setup -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateEmail(email) { 
        var reg = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
        return reg.test(email);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".modalbox").fancybox();
        $("#contact").submit(function() { return false; });


        $("#send").on("click", function(){
            var emailval  = $("#email").val();
            var msgval    = $("#msg").val();
            var msglen    = msgval.length;
            var mailvalid = validateEmail(emailval);

            if(mailvalid == false) {
                $("#email").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(mailvalid == true){
                $("#email").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(msglen < 4) {
                $("#msg").addClass("error");
            }
            else if(msglen >= 4){
                $("#msg").removeClass("error");
            }

            if(mailvalid == true && msglen >= 4) {
                // if both validate we attempt to send the e-mail
                // first we hide the submit btn so the user doesnt click twice
                $("#send").replaceWith("<em>en cours d'envoi</em>");

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'sendmessage.php',
                    data: $("#contact").serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data == "true") {
                            $("#contact").fadeOut("slow", function(){
                                $(this).before("<p><strong>Merci de votre interet, bonne journee</strong></p>");
                                setTimeout("$.fancybox.close()", 4000);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**And the php:**

```
 <?php
$sendto   = "hello@tiphainebuccino.com";
$usermail = $_POST['email'];
$content  = nl2br($_POST['msg']);

$subject  = "La Couleur Du Rendez Vous";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>New User Feedback</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Sent by:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Message:</strong> ".$content."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";


if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you check your spam folder? Otherwise it's probably a mail-server misconfiguration

Comment: are you checked in spam folder?

Comment: Unrelated but, please, never use `@function()`. `@` is a terrible operator. Handle errors, don't avoid them.

Comment: A note: `"From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n"` is really horrible as someone will be able to use your contact form to send spam messages to anyone. The same is with the `Reply-To` line.

Comment: Looking at the IP of your domain and checking it agains [spamhaus.org](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/) shows that you are on the **[XBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/Spamhaus%20XBL)**. So the server you are on sends or has sended SPAM, and is for that blocked by every service that checks the IPs agains spamhaus.org and I guess it is listed also on other lists then.

Comment: Dis you try to submit the contact form with a standard POST ? It could help you to see what is happening.

Comment: @Loenix A standard POST ? Don't know what it means, but if you explain me I would sure try it !

Comment: @t.niese What should I write instead of "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n" and Reply-To lines ??

Comment: You at least need to make sure that `$usermail` can not contain `\r` and `\n`. **BUT** if you don't know anything about the internals of emails and not about the basic attack vectors then you should not run a homebrew email composer, but you should use a maintained and proofed library to create the email even if you have knowledge about that you would avoid not using a library. I really hope you don't run a server your self being responsible for the mailserver. If so you have a real problem.